# Cannot locate BeanDefinitionDecorator for element [set]

Tags: xml, spring

I have `spring xml config` with schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
```

With a property for bean definition:

```
 <property name="airDates">
      <util:set set-class="java.util.TreeSet">
          <ref bean="first_event_dateTime"/>
      </util:set>
 </property>

 <bean
        name="first_event_dateTime"
        class="java.time.LocalDateTime"
        factory-method="of">
    <constructor-arg type="int" value="2020"/>
    <constructor-arg type="int" value="6"/>
    <constructor-arg type="int" value="15"/>
    <constructor-arg type="int" value="19"/>
    <constructor-arg type="int" value="30"/>
</bean>
```

Target of injection is `NavigableSet` with setter and getter accordingly

```
private NavigableSet<LocalDateTime> airDates = new TreeSet<>();
```

---

The problem is:
1) my IDE highlights `util:set` and says Bean must be one of these types:

> Bean must be one of these types: java.time.LocalDateTime or
>   java.util.NavigableSet

2) Spring execution says to me:

> Cannot locate BeanDefinitionDecorator for element [set]

Do you have any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: The problem actually was: I used         
            <set>
                <ref bean="some_bean"/>
            <set>
        </property>` without `property` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please provide a definition of first_event_dateTime

UPDATE: following definition works good at my environment:

XML:

```
...
<bean
    name="first_event_dateTime" class="java.time.LocalDateTime" factory-method="of">
    <constructor-arg type="int" value="2020"/>
    <constructor-arg type="int" value="6"/>
    <constructor-arg type="int" value="15"/>
    <constructor-arg type="int" value="19"/>
    <constructor-arg type="int" value="30"/>
</bean>
...
<bean id="client" class="<my package>.Client"
    <property name="airDates">
        <util:set set-class="java.util.TreeSet">
            <ref bean="first_event_dateTime"/>
        </util:set>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Java:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.NavigableSet;

public class Client {

  private NavigableSet<LocalDateTime> airDates;

  public NavigableSet<LocalDateTime> getAirDates() {
    return airDates;
  }

  public void setAirDates(NavigableSet<LocalDateTime> airDates) {
    this.airDates = airDates;
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: the definition of first_event_dateTime is added

Comment: from log: "43538#Mar 27, 2016 1:40:48 PM: airDates of client: [2020-06-15T19:30]"